# why is this unsafe for mysql replication

Tags: mysql, replication

```
121214 11:54:30 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave. Statement: update db_ds_pax p
        set p.mbp_id = 8861912, updated_ts = now()
        where p.flight_id = 2506912 
        and p.logically_deleted = 0
        and (
            exists (
                    select * from db_bkg_passenger bkgp 
                    where bkgp.bkg_pax_id = p.bkg_pax_id
                    and bkgp.ticket_num = '2202326623256'
                    and bkgp.logically_deleted = 0 )
            or exists (
                    select * from db_dcs_pax dcsp 
                    where dcsp.dcs_pax_id = p.dcs_pax_id
                    and dcsp.ticket_num = '2202326623256'
                    and dcsp.logically_deleted = 0 ))
```

What is unsafe in this statement? I'm not inserting anything, just updating. I'm actually not even selecting anything that will be used for updating.

I have tried to rewrite using left joins, but it still complains. I also thought maybe `updated_ts = now()` is the culprit and have set it to the fixed time, but still the same warning.

server is Oracle's 5.5.27

Comment: If you scroll right you'll see the explanation in the warning message.

Comment: But I'm not inserting the contents of my select, it is just used as a check

Answer (score 0):

> Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave

I did nothing but copy-pasted the explanation from the warning message.

So seems like `UPDATE` is treated as a "writing to a table"

Comment: Yes, but in my case that explanation doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Aleksandar Ivanisevic: well, seems like mysql doesn't perform any deep analysis of what exactly you're selecting.